# Magento : How Do I Loop Product Categories and Pull Out X Products From It

Tags: magento-1.9, product, category

I have been bit of trouble trying to figure this out.

Essentially on homepage I'm trying to to pull 3 products from 4 different categories.

Category 1 
- Product 1 
- Product 2 
- Product 3

Category 2
- Product 1
- Product 2
- Product 3

Category 3
- Product 1
- Product 2
- Product 3

Category 4
- Product 1
- Product 2
- Product 3

I'll be using jquery/css to make a tabbed component like first example here: http://refills.bourbon.io/

I'm having a real difficult time figuring out how to loop through though.

Comment: Are you talking about a rotation of products - you want to be able to rotate the products?

Answer (score 0):

try below code

```
<?php
$categories = array(1,2,3,4);
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array('in'=>$categories));
?>
<ul class="accordion-tabs">
<?php
foreach($category as $cat) { ?>
    <li class="tab-header-and-content">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="is-active tab-link"><?php  echo $cat->getName() ?></a>
        <div class="tab-content">
            <?php
            $products = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($cat->getId())
                ->getProductCollection()
                ->addAttributeToSelect('*') 
                ->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1)
                ->getSelect()->limit(3);

            foreach($products as $product)
            {
                echo $product->getName()."</br>";
                echo $product->getFinalPrice()."</br>";
            }
            ?>
        </div>
    </li>

<?php } ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: this seems to be working but for some reason the price isn't rendering. I'm supposed to use <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true); ?> right?

Comment: @kkyang find updated answer and if you find this answer helpful then upvote it and mark it as accept to close the question